# Laravel doesn't send forgot password link

Tags: laravel

After I changed my shared host, I have problem with Forgot password link. In my app all sections need to send email work fine but when I pressed forgot password button I got success alert that link sent to your email but when I checked my mails it was empty!!(app doesn't send link)
I checked all my logs in app and host there weren't any error.
I use default Laravel settings.(Laravel 7).

Comment: Have you changed your mail config with new hosting provider? Have you checked the fact that your new provider has mail server?

Comment: yes. I did all of them. Other sections send email fine just this section avoid to send email

Comment: Make your your `MAIL_MAILER` set to `smtp` on your `.env`

Comment: absolutely I did these configs. I could send mail with my app just I couldn't send forgot password link

Answer (score 0):

In .env file add new variable called **MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=your_smtp_from_mail_id** . you have to set **MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS** to valid SMTP from_mail email id. sometimes in the .env file, this variable doesn't exist. if it is not set manually; when sending mail it is picking up a default mail id which is hello@example.com. please have look here **config/mail.php**

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

i think this should work !

This worked for me.